# Using block expectations with OCMock

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, objective-c-blocks, ocmock, nsinvocation

I am using GHUnit & OCMock to do some testing work in my iOS app.

So I have some trouble integrating them.

The following code works well.

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithString:@"122"];
id mock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:s];
[[[mock stub] andReturn:@"255"] capitalizedString];
NSString *returnValue = [mock capitalizedString];
GHAssertEqualObjects(returnValue, @"255", @"Should be equal");
[mock verify];
```

But when I change [[[mock stub] andReturn:@"255"] capitalizedString]; into

```
[[[mock stub] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
    [invocation setReturnValue:@"255"];
}] capitalizedString];
```

I got an error which says "Reason: 'NSCFString' should be equal to '255'. Should be equal"

I think the two statements should do exactly the same thing. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setReturnValue:` expects a pointer to the return value, so your block should be:

```
void (^theBlock)(NSInvocation *) = ^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
    NSString *capitalizedString = @"255";
    [invocation setReturnValue:&capitalizedString];
};
```

Comment: @leafduo `GHUnit` and `OCMock` are both not from Apple.

Comment: @ThomasW I think he's referring to the [NSInvocation docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000212-setReturnValue_)